# and then only poignantly so

Tags: meaning-in-context

Am I right about the meaning of "and then only poignantly so" in the quote below? I think it means "... except the hope for life itself, which it would be a very sad and upsetting feeling too"

> The rich and powerful can own art and corral off nature but nothing is beautiful if you are starving, oppressed or dying, except the hope for life itself and then only poignantly so.

(From *Art and Science* by Sian Ede.)

Comment: Sounds good to me (as I'm finding myself unable to describe [*poignant*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/poignant) without using copious amounts of pejorative language). What I don't get is *corral off nature*.

Comment: The more I see if this book by Sian Ede the less I'm liking it. Unfounded assertion after unfounded assertion. *Nothing is beautiful if you are starving, oppressed or dying except the hope for life itself.* I very much doubt that. http://www.aboriginalartonline.com/latest.php for example: an oppressed people noticing and expressing the beauty of nature.

Comment: I'm amazed you're still slogging through that same book. It's alternately obscure, obtuse, enigmatic and inscrutable, isn't it? Rough going even for native speakers. Entertaining at times, but as some have noted, Ede's style temds to run toward the overblown, the self-impressed, the words-for-words' sake. He probably lives to hear himself talk.

Comment: @Brian Hitchcock  yes! I am still reading the same book, because I find interesting ideas in this book. And, is your real family "Hitchcock"?  ;)

Comment: Yes, but no known relation to Alfred. He emigrated from England in the 20th century; my Hitchcock ancestors emigrated to America in the 17th century (14 generations ago).

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation is on the right lines but stops short of Ede's intention. I believe Ede means that the hope of life may seem beautiful but only in an acutely painful way (as in a stabbing, referring to the etymology of poignant). Perhaps like the beauty of a wonderful dawn on the day you were to be executed. Ede wants you to imagine sharp pain, not merely sadness.

Comment: Sunny day execution, nice example.